# Shared Image between Activities through Glide

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, android-glide

I was building an App using images in the drawable, but since they were too much I stored them in Firebase.

Now, whilst working with drawable everything was fine, but now that I use Glide and the Images aren't in the drawable I'm stuck.

I have a RecyclerView with 9 CardViews (= Class CardView Item + AdapterClass etc etc...).

In the Main Fragment I had created the list with

```
list.add(new SpeciesItem("Name", "Description", R.id.picture);
```

But now I have a download url instead of the drawable reference.
After changing everything accordingly I got back to the point where the images in the CardViews are loaded (Now through Glide), and now here comes my problem:

When clicked, the CardView expanded to a new Activity with shared elements(Name and Picture).

The name sharing still works of course through `Name.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));` because I had used intents.

I can't do something like `Glide.with(this).load(intent.getIntExtra("image", 0)).into(ImageView);`

But I can't either `Glide.with(this).load(List.get(position).getPicture).into(ImageView)` because this is a new Activity and I'd have no idea on how to summon the CardView ArrayList.

How do I share a picture loaded through Glide in a CardView into an ImageView inside a different Activity?

Comment: Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont pass name and drawable. Pass name and url of image to next activity.
These libraries load the images in the cache. You can reload the image in another activity passing same photo url. instead of loading it from firebase. It will load it from local storage.

Comment: OH it works! Now that you said it looks so obvious to me, I feel stupid, thanks a lot!